# Не работает функция, из-за глобально переменной

Tags: php

Если так то все нормально

```
function getPassword() { 
    $length = 12;                                       
$password = getRandomPassword();
    do {
       $password = getRandomPassword();
    } while(iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $length);
    return $password;
```

но если `$length`сделать глобальной и локализовать ее:

```
$length = 12;
function getPassword() { 
$L_length = $length;                                            
$password = getRandomPassword();
    do {
       $password = getRandomPassword();
    } while(iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $L_length);
    return $password;
```

то выдает `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: А как у Вас `$length` попадает в функцию? У Вас бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб переменная была глобальной, мало вынести за пределы видимости функции, это надо еще и указать, тут вам не `JS`.

```
$length = 12;
function getPassword() {
global $length;  // <--- Воть
$L_length = $length;                                            
$password = getRandomPassword();
    do {
       $password = getRandomPassword();
    } while(iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $L_length);
    return $password;
```

---

Почитать в туалетике: [Область видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: спосеба) незнал